# c++ string comparison in if statement

Tags: c++, string-comparison

i have a question about a simple c++ function.
This is my cpp file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <json_prolog/prolog.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace json_prolog;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "Knives");

  Prolog pl;
char M[]="drawer";
cout<<M<<endl;
if(strcmp(M,"knife")==0)
{
    string  q= "rdfs_individual_of(M, 'http://knowrob.org/kb/knowrob.owl#TableKnife')";



PrologQueryProxy bdgs = pl.query(q);

        cout<< endl;

  for(PrologQueryProxy::iterator it=bdgs.begin(); it != bdgs.end(); it++)
  {
    PrologBindings bdg = *it;
    cout << "Knives individuals= "<< bdg["M"] << endl;
  }  

    cout<< endl<< endl;
}


if(strcmp(M,"drawer")==0)
{
    string  q= "rdfs_individual_of(M, 'http://knowrob.org/kb/knowrob.owl#Drawer')";

  PrologQueryProxy bdgs = pl.query(q);

        cout<< endl;

  for(PrologQueryProxy::iterator it=bdgs.begin(); it != bdgs.end(); it++)
  {
    PrologBindings bdg = *it;
    cout << "Drawer individuals= "<< bdg["M"] << endl;
  }  

    cout<< endl<< endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

this code is connect with an xml file to parse it.
if i compile it works and i have no problems.
Now i have to change it,because i don't want to define the variable char M but i want to give it in input. the problem is that i change :

```
char M[]=....
```

with:

```
char M;
cin>>M;
```

i have a problem about the conversion from char to const char [-fpermissive]

how i can solve it?

Comment: Do you mean cin >> M? As it's written, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: _"because i don't want to define the variable `char M` but i want to give it in input"_ Uhm what please? You cannot read a string into a single character.

Comment: `cin<<M` makes no sense, and `char` (a single character) is very different from `char[]` (an array of characters).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is correct, and further, since this is C++, why not use std::string instead of cstrings?

Comment: Learn basic C++, then copy codes. `<<` for `std::cin` ?

Comment: obviously it was c>> i've got a mistake come on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
std::string M;
cin >> M;
```

replace lines like this:

```
if(strcmp(M,"drawer")==0)
```

with this:

```
if (M == "drawer" )
```

Comment: but can i do the same with a switch instead of the two if?
because i know that switch should work only with integer

Answer (score 2):

Why did you change an array of `char`s (`char M[] = ...;`) to a single `char` (`char M;`)? Aside from the other answer suggesting using a `std::string` instead (which you should do), if you must use an array of `char` variables, you need to use `std::unique_ptr<char> M(new char[100])` before use in `std::cin` (I've assumed 100 `char`s are enough to hold the input; change as necessary).

Comment: Even a `std::unique_ptr<char>` is better than recommending raw memory allocation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Fair enough, will make that change.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string M = "drawer";
cout<<M<<endl;
if(M.compare("knife") == 0)
{
    // do whatever
}

You can also do:
if(M == "knife")
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Unless you need to use C strings, why would you not use the standard library string?  No reason to make life more difficult.